# Windows 7 Pro x64, Visual Studio 2017 x64, SSIS/SSAS/SSRS x64, SSDT x64, SQL Server 2014 x64 - compatibility issues?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, ssis-2014

I had to introduce SSIS into my work with SQL Server due to several requirements of the business, as I could not implement changes using other means readily available in standard installation of SQL Server and SSMS.

Up until the SSIS requirement everything was working fine: SSMS hummed nicely, had VS2010 shell for deploying SSRS reports directly to the server and to be able to maintain my reports better than using Report Builder. But it was insufficient for several projects, so SSIS was chosen to deal with that deficiency.

Everything works fine up to the moment of deploying the package. Develop, test and build - package works like a charm. But deployed package just would not work. Troubleshooting pointed to 32/64 bit issue and only after an option "32-bit runtime" checked in advanced configuration in Server Agent job properties. How is that possible when the everything I installed and used is 64-bit? Obviously, that presents additional issues (ODBC drivers, other applications all need 32 bit versions) and resolving those is not as obvious as Microsoft think it is, if it's possible at all.

And then, following logic: how can I set up truly end-to-end 64-bit environment with Microsoft Stack?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using a flat file connection to connect to the file. Am I correct in guessing so? If so, the reason is simple, BIDS is a 32bit application; it can't make use of 64 bit drivers (BIDS is 10 years old now, and many people were still using 32bit OS's back then, so 32bit made sense).

Comment: @Larnu - Amended question as you raised some points. So, scrapped BIDS, as it was a force of habit that it was mentioned at all. Please see improved question.

Comment: I'll admit, I'm not entirely sure what your question is here. You start off by making a statement about that sometimes one of your (deployed?) packages fails. You don't discuss any of the error messages, however, and just say it runs fine in SSDT. Then you suddenly have a change of pace and ask why do you have to use 32bit drivers? Well, for a text file 9which a csv is) you don't have to; just use the Flat File Connection. If, you're using the Excel Connection Manager, then you have to if you're using a 32bit version of SSDT. A 32 bit application can't use 64bit drivers, even on a 64bit host.

Comment: @Larnu - reworked the question yet again. SOrry for previous attempts. No excuse, even if there were reasons I bungled it up in earlier attempts.

Comment: Likely, the reason, is because you only have 32bit drivers for something you are using, and thus when using the package, you have to run in 32bit mode. A "great" example of this is the ACE Drivers. When in SSDT, the application is 32bit, so **has** to use the 32 drivers. If you're SQL Server also, only has the 32 bit drivers installed (not the 64 bit) then, again, you have to use the 32bit run-time option. It's all; about what drivers you are using. if you don't have 64bit drivers for what you're doing, but have 32bit ones, you have run in 32bit (and vice versa).

Comment: @Larnu How then I could debug, test and deploy my package in 64 Bit successfully, without 32-bit drivers (not without needing them; I had no 32 bit drivers present in my system then) required when I force "32-bit runtime" in SQL Agent?

Comment: You can also run packages in 32 bit in SSDT. I recommend creating a separate project for these, however, as it's a project level setting in SSDT. Right Click your Project in the Solution Explorer and select Properties. Then go to the Configuration Properties/Debugging pane and change Run64bitRuntime to False.

Comment: Note that if a package needs to run in 32bit mode, then it needs to run in it. You can't force it to run in 64bit mode and expect it to work. Thus, it's best to create and debug it in SSDT in 32bit mode as well.

Comment: @Larnu - already using that. The issue is - why do I have to? Why I have to go 32-bit at all? If you say SSDT is 32-bit only then that explains that, but not why I need 32-bit drivers etc only when running SQL Agent job on this package? Again: I had no 32 bit drivers before I actually tried to schedule the package in SQL Agent. It even deployed in 64 bit.

Comment: I've already explained why 32bit has to be used several times above...

Comment: @Larnu - sorry, I don't believe you did. SSDT is 32-bit, but then you yourself noted there is a parameter "Run64bitRuntime". If I have 64-bit environment (Win7) with 64-bit drivers, I'm deploying to 64 bit server running on same 64-bit environment a package built to 64-bit specification why I need to have it in 32-bit compatible mode in SQL Agent? All your explanations are fine for "how to fix it", but not for "why it happened at all". If you're not yet annoyed by my denseness can you reply as an answer, please, instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

To quote my point from the comments:

> Likely, the reason, is because you only have 32bit drivers for
>   something you are using, and thus when using the package, you have to
>   run in 32bit mode. A "great" example of this is the ACE Drivers. When
>   in SSDT, the application is 32bit, so has to use the 32 drivers. **If
>   your SQL Server also, only has the 32 bit drivers installed** (not
>   the 64 bit) then, again, you have to use the 32bit run-time option.
>   It's all about **what drivers you are using**. If you don't have 64bit
>   drivers for what you're doing, but have 32bit ones, you have run in
>   32bit (and vice versa).

Couple of bits emphasised.

Comment: Thank you. My question still stands: I had to **install 32 bit drivers** only **after** my **64-bit deployed** package **had to be run in 32 bit runtime** by **64-bit SQL Server Agent** and **only after that forced compatibility to 32 bit** I had to **install 32 bit drivers** in order for that package to run successfully. Why? Package involves calling SP on remote SQL Server and then copy result of that SP into a table on yet another SQL server. All 64-bit.

Comment: Most likely, for whatever reason, your Instance was unable to use those 64 drivers, or they weren't installed correctly. Historically, for example, the 64bit version of the ACE drivers didn't work with SQL Server (I believe they do now, but i haven't tested on a 2016/2017 instance). If you were accessing a .xls file (rather than a .xlsx) then you had to use 32bit, as JET doesn't support 64 bit (as it's old tech). As for why your instance doesn't support it, that could be the driver's, or SQL Server's fault. I've found that it can be either (which I admit, is frustrating).